# Prime ideals of $M_{n,n}(R)$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. Denote $M_{n,n}(R)$ as the matrix ring over $R$. I've already proven that $M_{n,n}(I)$ is an ideal of $M_{n,n}(R)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

Is there a short way to prove that $M_{n,n}(I)$ is a prime ideal of $M_{n,n}(R)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $I$ is a prime ideal of $R$?

note: every ideal is considered to be two-sided.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false.

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$.
The kernel of the ring homomorphism $M_{n,n}(R)\to M_{n,n}(R/I)$ (component-wise) is $M_{n,n}(I)$ so that we have $M_{n,n}(R)/M_{n,n}(I)\cong M_{n,n}(R/I)$.
Note that for $n>1$ and $I\ne R$ the latter will have non-trivial zero divisors such as $\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, even if $R/I$ has no zero-divisors!

Comment: No: the definition of prime ideals in noncommutative rings is such that this claim is true. The quotient is still a *prime ring* (the noncommutative analogue of an integral domain). So, for example, the ring of matrices over a field is a prime ring while still having zero divisors.